# Kill third party application I started

Tags: android

I am building an application where I will be utilizing VLC on Android for playing different kind of video feeds.

From my application I will be starting VLC when the user clicks on a video feed. I would like to be able to close VLC again from my application, but as far as I can read in the documentation, this is not possible due to security reasons.

I have found a lot of different posts here on SO but they are somehow always related to closing an activity which is in the developers control and not a third party application.

I will be using something like this from https://wiki.videolan.org/Android_Player_Intents/ to start VLC:

```
 int vlcRequestCode = 42;
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/KUNG FURY Official Movie.mp4");
 Intent vlcIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 vlcIntent.setPackage("org.videolan.vlc");
 vlcIntent.setDataAndTypeAndNormalize(uri, "video/*");
 vlcIntent.putExtra("title", "Kung Fury");
 vlcIntent.putExtra("from_start", false);
 vlcIntent.putExtra("position", 90000l);
 vlcIntent.putExtra("subtitles_location", "/sdcard/Movies/Fifty-Fifty.srt");
 startActivityForResult(vlcIntent, vlcRequestCode);
```

Overall question: How to close a third party application that I started from my own application?

Comment: your app cannot close/control another app

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that was the answer. Back to the drawing board.